# Basic NE555 assembly exhibits voltage spike

Tags: oscilloscope, 555, spike

I have below the most basic NE555 assembly and I observe a voltage spike in my signal with the oscilloscope.

[image]
[image: montage]

I am barely jumping back on the electronic wagon after 20 years, so I may miss something obvious (a diode or capacitor I guess ?).

Also, when the output is connected to a buzzer, the signal get very noisy, as a follow up question.

Comment: Wheres you decoupling capacitor? The NE555 is known to have issues with shoot through.

Comment: And a schematic would be great :) For the oscilloscope: make the x / time interval smaller, and check the slope with some extra decoupling (+resistor?)

Comment: That could very easily be a problem with how you're probing the circuit, too.

Comment: @user1937198 It was exactly that! I also added a decoupling capacitor in front of the buzzer that is clean the noise under load quite well. The basic astable reference schematic for the NE555 should mention the need for decoupling !

Comment: @galop1n All digital or analog circuits NEED decoupling nearest their supply pins ... It is the first rule of design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totem-pole outputs (inside the 555), connected directly to the positive rail and ground, without any kind of current limiting or special switch timing, that allows both transistors to be on very briefly, drawing large currents. Typical reports are of a current spike that lasts 100-200 nsec and pulls about 300 mA. This is more than 30 times the normal unloaded current drawn by the chip. One thing to be aware of is the well-documented [supply current spike](https://www.edn.com/the-ne555-current-spike/) created as the output changes state (**particularly from low to high**). A bypass capacitor is always needed to handle this, and the minimum is 10µF.
The average 555 simulations models do not show the current drawn from the supply voltage, so the peaks are not visible either, but that still makes them exist. Suggested values for the bypass capacitor vary between 1 uF and 47 uF.
As close as possible to the 555's GND and VCC pins.

My modified 555 model shows both supply currents and ground currents, because they can be both when, for example, a MOSFET is directly controlled with it.[image]
[image]

At a lower supply voltage, the peaks are also smaller, which requires smaller capacitors. We always use a smaller ceramic capacitor in parallel with an electrolytic capacitor so that the high-frequency filtering is also effective. The peaks are narrow (150 ns), so high-frequency capacitors are also needed.

Mounted on a test panel, put the capacitors directly on the pins of the 555.

Comment: What simulation software are you using?

Comment: I mostly use the TINA and TINA-TI programs, I'm used to them and I have many of my own models for them.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple reasons for that spike. The pictue is excellent reference to see the reasons.

-using breadboard. It has poor connections for high speed digital signals, there are lot of stray capacitances and inductances.

-using long jumper wires to connect components. Lot of stray inductances.

-omitting bypass caps. Stray inductances cause jump in voltage when there is a jump in current.

-having the scope ground clip connected through long jumper wire. It does not reference to the chip ground directly, due to stray inductance of the wire.

So the spike may either actually exist, or, the scope just sees it exist due to long ground clip connection.

Comment: The measurement method could definitely be a part of it. I tried again as close as possible to the output and gnd, no noticeable difference. The decoupling cap WAS the solution (+1 for buzzer as well).